Android 7.0 Autostart Service doesnt Work
I am currently making a app that starts a http server service on boot. It worked at first but it randomly stopped working.
This is my AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="me.rapierxbox.TestApp.BootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".HttpServer" />
    </application>
</manifest>

and this is my BootReciver:
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("autostart","autostart recived");
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, HttpServer.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}

Even when I broadcast the Intend myself using ./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED I get no Logcat logs and neither the service starts.

Be sure you launch your activity from time to time or your app ends up being thrown in inactive bucket and it can no longer receive static broadcasts.

Can I prevent this without launching the activity automaticly... planning on removing it entirely.

Sorry didn't notice android 7 in title since it's rather old and activity buckets were introduced in android 9. Generally autostarting stuff / running permanently is a gray area as every manufacturer messes with battery optimizations so despite best efforts  it's never a guarantee.

The device has no battery...

You'd have to use androidx.legacy.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver (meanwhile deprecated).
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-core-utils
runtimeOnly "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0"


Works most of the time! But it still sometimes just wont work. Logging says the reciver doesnt even get triggered.
